# Angular 8 when i receive web socket message all service injected became undefined

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, websocket, angular-material

I implemented websocket in both side (backend & frontend)
i receive the message from backend
the probleme is when i want to display message received in MatDialog Or in ToAstr. both of them became undefined
my component code below

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-upload-excel-file',
 templateUrl: './upload-excel-file.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./upload-excel-file.component.scss']
})
export class UploadExcelFileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(

    private websocketService: UploadWebsocketService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.connect();
  }
  connect() {
    const obs = this.websocketService.getObservable();
    obs.subscribe(
      this.onMessageReceived,
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
  } 
  public onMessageReceived(receivedMsg) {
    if (receivedMsg && receivedMsg.type === 'SUCCESS') {
    /* Todo update notification icon */
    const res = receivedMsg.message;
    this.toastr.info(res.success, 'result');
    this.dialog.open(ListDialogComponent, {
      closeOnNavigation: false,
      disableClose: true,
      data: res
    }).afterClosed().subscribe();
   }
  }
 }
```

On init of component all work good, but when i receive an message in websocket i have error that the service in undefined

Comment: Instead of `this.onMessageReceived` for your `next` callback, use an arrow function `(receivedMsg) => this.onMessageReceived(receivedMessage)`

Comment: What do you mean by they become undefined? Where they defined before?

Comment: @Sajad yes of course, i added a console.log in onInit function and both objects were defined

Comment: @JasonWhite thanks, i should juste change call function to arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i juste change this.onMessageReceived to arrow function and it work for me

Comment: That's what I looked for! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is with your `next` callback when you subscribe to your observable.  When you say `this.onMessageReceived`, you're passing a reference the function `onMessageReceived`.  When you pass a function this way you lose your `this`.  If you were to print `this` in the `onMessageReceived` you will notice that the `this` is now what you're expecting it to be.

Now there are two solutions for this.  A simple one is to just use an arrow function as your `next` callback in your subscription.

```js
const obs = this.websocketService.getObservable();
obs.subscribe(
  (receivedMsg) => this.onMessageReceived(receivedMsg),
  (err) => console.log(err)
);
```

Or you can choose to bind the proper `this` to the `onMessageReceived` function in your constructor.

```js
export class UploadExcelFileComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private websocketService: UploadWebsocketService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    // Bind your this
    this.onMessageReceived = this.onMessageReceived.bind(this);
  }
}
```